# Qt Application quits after slot of QAction gets triggered

Tags: c++, qt, action, exit

I've created an action for my QMenu and connected it to a slot "action1" like this

```
connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(action1()));
```

but when i execute this code, my application quits.

How to solve this?

Comment: There's nothing visibly wrong in the line you show. Is there any message printed to the console when the program exits? Have you run your program through a debugger to see if it's failing with a segmentation fault or some other error?

Comment: Please... more code... We can't see anything in this code...

Comment: That should happen only if action is invalid (or this, which is more unlikely (but can happen when using e.g. processEvents()). As Kamil said, we need more context.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a multitude of things, but for starters:

- Is the "triggered" signal also connected to another slot? e.g. the "quit" slot of the application?
- Does "action1" close the window? I seem to remember that Qt by default quits the application when the last window is closed.